# FTIR powder sample without KBr - is it allowed?

Tags: spectroscopy, experimental-technique

My team measures some nanoparticle powder in reflectance mode. In all the sources [[1]](http://www.shimadzu.com/an/ftir/support/ftirtalk/talk8/intro.html)[[2]](http://www.niu.edu/analyticallab/ftir/samplepreparation.shtml)[3] I found that for powder measurement you need to mix it with KBr.
However my team just put manually compressed powder (without KBr) on the sampleholder and collect data. Is it a good approach?

[3] Infrared Spectroscopy - fundamentals and applications by Barbara Stuart

Answer (score 2):

Using a pellet / matrix of KBr is a typical setup for recording IR spectra in *transmission mode* frequently used in chemistry labs.  This is a salty, ionic environment for your compound; in contrast to using nujol as an unpolar medium.  Because of the different environment, the position of the absorption bands may shift a little (if recording between $4000$ to about $600~\text{cm}^{-1}$, lesser than $10~\text{cm}^{-1}$). In both variants share that the matrix serves as transparent "solvent".  An increase of the analyte concentration by reducing the relative amount of KBr, and omitting the KBr entirely will render your sample "too dense", i.e. absorption bands that naturally are intense will absorb the radiation so intensely that they eventually hit the 0% remnant transmittance level, which disables you to extract useful information.

The alternative method is the one based on attenuated total reflection ([ATR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuated_total_reflectance)), gaining popularity (especially with the FT-IR spectrometers with single reflection geometry) because sample preparation is greatly simplified which often means the sample is recorded as neat film (at 100% concentration).  Hence you may get rid off absorption bands of your matrix material that are superimposed to absorption bands of your analyte, and chemical interference / reaction between your sample and KBr. Accessible samples may be solids, pastes, finely grind powders, or liquids -- easily and rapidly characterised; just put them in front of your optical window (Germanium crystal, diamond, for example). This may be on top of a table -- likely suitable for you

[image]

([source](http://community.asdlib.org/imageandvideoexchangeforum/2013/07/29/ft-ir-spectrometer/))

or while being immersed in the medium (react IR)

[image]

([doi 10.1039/C0CC01921F](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2010/cc/c0cc01921f))

To account for the wavelength dependent penetration depth of the evanescent waves into your sample material, the ATR spectrometers often posses a proper ATR correction, too.